# Python JSON GET Request Like cURL

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, curl, get

I have a cURL command that I would like to port to Python.

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/nuix-7674bc4a60b74ea7bac8996a98b0cb94;item;schema-version=1/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "content": "(p)hotos"
    }
  }
}'
```

It successfully returns a non-error response.

Here is what I tried in Python 3.6 using the `requests` package.

```
import requests
import json

# api-endpoint
url = "http://localhost:9200/nuix-7674bc4a60b74ea7bac8996a98b0cb94;item;schema-version=1/_search"

# headers
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}

# Define JSON String
params = """
{
    "query": {
        "regexp":{
            "content": "(p)hotos"
        }
    }
}
"""

params = json.loads(params)
print(params)

# sending get request and saving the response as response object
response = requests.get(url=url, params=params, headers=headers)

# extracting data in json format
data = response.json()
print(data['hits']['total'])
print('DONE')
```

The response `response._content` states this error:

```
b'{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"request [/nuix-7674bc4a60b74ea7bac8996a98b0cb94;item;schema-version=1/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [query]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"request [/nuix-7674bc4a60b74ea7bac8996a98b0cb94;item;schema-version=1/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [query]"},"status":400}'
```

What is the correct way to set `params`?

Comment: Using cURL in Windows, it is necessary to adjust quotes like this: `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/nuix-7674bc4a60b74ea7bac8996a98b0cb94;item;schema-version=1/_search" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"query\": {\"regexp\": {\"content\": \"(p)hotos\"}}}"`

Answer (score 0):

`requests` expects a `dict` as `params` not a string. I'm not sure this is your problem but you could try rewriting as:

```
params = {
    "query": {
        "regexp":{
            "content": "(p)hotos"
        }
    }
}
```

Check out this section from the docs for a walkthrough: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the `json` parameter, rather than `params`.

```
response = requests.get(url=url, json=params, headers=headers)
```

I probably could have rewritten the JSON string to a dictionary, but I am using a tool -- Kibana that automatically generates a cURL payload. This solution allows me to copy and paste the JSON payload into my Python script.